# Task management, reminder, or todo software with repeating reminders

Tags: project-management, time-management, productivity, reminders, todo

Example scenario:

1. I assign some tasks to my kids (who also have access to the software). Maybe a few weekly tasks like clean your room, and a daily task like complete your homework.
2. If they don’t mark it complete before the due date, the software can **send an e-mail or SMS text reminder every day** until the task is completed.

Maybe even a simple project management app might suffice, if it could be setup with periodic tasks and repeating follow ups.

The important requirements are that the reminders can be recurring, and that SMS/text can be used in addition to e-mail followups.

I’ll take anything. Windows app, mobile app for iOS or Android, etc.

Comment: @unor thanks for the help on the edits.  I did add back the time management tag because it applies in this case.

Comment: I think the tag is meant for time trackers, where users track how long (or when) they work on specific tasks. As far as I understand your question, it doesn’t matter *how long* the kid needs for cleaning the room, it only matters *that* it gets done. Or should the solution also feature such an option?

Comment: @unor This is absolutely relevant: “efficient use and control of the time in specific tasks“.  To answer your question, I think it’s implied, in that most forms of managed tasks do not have unbounded time limits with no impact on productivity. In fact, you could argue the very concept of a “reminder” means that time of completion is significant.

Comment: In my opinion, the combination of the two tags [tag:reminders] and [tag:todo] covers exactly your use case. The third tag [tag:time-management] suggests that another component is needed: e.g., a feature where users track *when* they start working on a task, to learn how long they needed to complete it. If users just check off a task as done (without entering a start/finish time), it’s just a todo app, not also a time management app (otherwise most [tag:todo] questions would warrant the [tag:time-management] tag). - But I don’t object to keeping this tag here, as it’s an informal one.

Comment: @unor I can see that viewpoint, but given the current definition and precision of the tag description I believe it’s a subjective interpretation.  I’ll leave it for now, but maybe the tag can be discussed on meta and made more specific.  It’s a living taxonomy here, so however it evolves I’m glad to modify as needed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Do you have a preference  for o/s, even if you will accept anything (the reason I ask is that there are so many ways to do this. Also, do you have a budget in mind, or must it be [tag:gratis]?

Comment: It would be great to have something that could work on iOS which many on the team have, so they could use a mobile device. The reason I say any, is that being well implemented and easy to use is more important. So if that meant everyone uses a Windows laptop, that’s fine.  Least efficient would be a stationary centralized system that the team stopped by and checked once a day (which could be Android not a phone something, MacOS, etc. So some could be convenient OS wise, but concern for an effective feature is why “any” is listed.

Comment: If it suffices for the kid to set up their own reminders on their own phone, look at [*Due* app](http://www.dueapp.com/) on iOS & macOS.

Comment: This has reminders that can be snoozed in small increments https://loophabits.org/